# iOS [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath] EXC_BAD_ACCESS issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, exc-bad-access

Here is the code below. It downloads a thumbnail image and then tries to create an image based on the thumbnail file path. But it gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS error at method call "imageWithContentsOfFile". While EXC_BAD_ACCESS addresses the code trying to access an object that has been released most likely I don't know which object it could be. Any help'd be appreciated!

```
NSBlockOperation *completionOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
            if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:operation.destinationPath ]){

               NSString *key = [[MEURLCacheKeyRegister sharedRegister] cacheKeyForURL:operation.fileUrl];

               UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:operation.destinationPath];
            }else{
                DDLogDebug(@"Thumbnail file doesn't exist at %@", operation.destinationPath);
            }
        }

    }];

AFDownloadRequestOperation *requestOperation = [FileServerDownloadUtils downloadOperationForURL:operation.fileUrl
                                                                                      destinationPath:operation.destinationPath
                                                                                           completion:completionOperation];
[self.fileSyncQueue addOperation:requestOperation];
```

Comment: Which line it crashes and what are you doing with `image` variable after loading in completion block?

Comment: Hi Abhinav, it crashed at line
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:operation.destinationPath];

Comment: operation is a custom NSOperation object BTW.

Comment: What are you doing with that `image` and also can you print your `destinationPath` and show here. I doubt if it contains image file name in the end.

Comment: I didn't post the usage of image object as it's not related to the problem I am having. The image file name is "beacon_preview.jpg.prv.jpg" and as you can see the file does exist. The same code works in other places.

Answer (score 0):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` indicates that object has been released while its being accessed.

If I were you, I would try following things:

1. Save the file with `.jpg` and not `.jpg.prv.jpg` extension.
2. Try using `initWithContentsOfFile` instead of `imageWithContentsOfFile` as `imageWithContentsOfFile` autoreleases image which in rare edge cases creates crashes like this.
3. When passing code to a `block`, access object properties by making weak reference to `self`. Something like this: `__weak MyController *weakSelf = self`. Then use `weakSelf` to access properties inside the block.

These are just few clues which may help you digging it further. You may use `NSZombie` and other profiling tools to nail it down.